# DBPedia load abstract from soccer club

Tags: sparql, ontology, dbpedia

Unfortunately I have a further problem with the ontology of dbpedia. I can't suggest how I can get the abstract from my selected teams. My sparql query looks like

```
PREFIX dbo:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT * where {
?club a dbo:SoccerClub;
dbo:ground ?grounds.
?grounds  dbo:location ?country.
FILTER(?country = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Austria>)
}
```

The result of this query looks like

[image: The result of this query looks like]

Have anyone an idea how I can select the abstract to each club?

Thanks for any help

Comment: So you're not able to add another triple pattern `?club dbo:abstract ?abstract .`? I guess you should be given that you understood the concept of SPARQL which is basically triple pattern matching. And indeed, it might be useful to filter by a particular language especially on DBpedia. `FILTER(LANGMATCHES ...)`

Comment: thank you very much. yes I tried to add another triple pattern 

`PREFIX dbo: <dbpedia.org/ontology/>; 
SELECT * where { 
?club a dbo:SoccerClub;
 ?club dbo:abstract ?abstract . 
dbo:ground ?grounds. ?grounds 
dbo:location ?country.
 FILTER(?country = <dbpedia.org/resource/Austria>) } 
`

but then the compiler throw an error: 

`
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL 
compiler, line 6: syntax error at '?abstract' before '.''
`

Comment: Well, you should learn about Turtle syntax then. `?club a dbo:SoccerClub;` the semicolon `;` is used as when the following triple pattern is using the same subject, which means you have to omit it: `?club a dbo:SoccerClub ; dbo:abstract ?abstract ; dbo:ground ?grounds .`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the right soloution by myself. thanks for your help.

```
PREFIX dbo:     <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT * where {
?club a dbo:SoccerClub;
dbo:ground ?grounds.
?grounds  dbo:location ?country.
?club dbo:abstract ?abstract.
FILTER(?country = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Austria> && langMatches(lang(?abstract),"de"))
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at Turtle short forms. `?club a dbo:SoccerClub ; dbo:abstract ?abstract ; dbo:ground ?grounds .`